# How to subtract an open path from another path in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs5, pathfinder

There are at least two similar questions on here already, but the thing being subtracted from is always a solid object. Please see image below for my situation. I have the two paths on the left and want to subtract the red path from the blue paths to end up with the 4 open paths on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the top path to make it a closed path.

Select the blue paths and make a compound path.

Select all and go to Pathfinder->Minus Front.

Use the Direct section Tool to select and delete the unwanted lines.

See the image below:

[image]